# Epson Scanner, part of XP-310 Printer, not working in Ubuntu GNOME 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, scanner, epson

I finally got printer working, but the scanner isn't being recognized... I have sane installed, but it is still as if I have no printer plugged in. "No printer detected", any suggestions as to how to make my Epson printer work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the printer to work, but not the scanner yet. Go into Synaptic Manager, and try to find XP-310. This video will give you a good start http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNbmSjOFrHE

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, yes, I got printer to work too! I had to manually get a driver off of Linux OpenPrinting. Still no scan capability, though - kind of a pity! Even Xsane gives me issues.

Answer (score 0):

My system is 14.04 64 bit and I'm printing and scanning on my XP-310.

I ran across a post suggesting the use of gdebi, an alternate package installer for *.deb packages. I installed gdebi through the Ubuntu Software Center.

The XP-301 driver is here as a .deb file: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=22524&DSCCHK=be2881cd731a22e340ed2e96eb71ee0725faab96#

I downloaded the driver then accessed the driver file though "Files". Next, I right-clicked on the *.deb driver file . I chose "open with gdebi". This installed the driver without a problem.

Then I went to "System Settings", "Printer", and was able to add the printer as a network printer. I used the LPD/LPR with the PASSTHRU queue option. Printing and Scanning now both work fine.